# Intelij + Tomee - IDE is using it's own tomcat instance

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

so I am trying to make an application running on TomEE and my IDE is Intelij. The problem is that I want to use my installation of TomEE, but the IDE is making it's own. I checked "Deploy applications configured in Tomcat instance" but still not working - the app is deployed, but I don't see it in webapps folder of the tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You operate under the misconception that "putting an app into the Tomcat/TomEE webapps folder" and "deploying an app in Tomcat/TomEE" are the same thing. They are not.

You can deploy an app in Tomcat/TomEE at any time, not just at startup. It basically means to give it a WAR-file or app folder, and tell it "here, run this", which it will do. This file or folder can be anywhere on your harddrive or network.

The sole purpose of the webapp folder is, that Tomcat/TomEE will check it at startup, and deploy all apps it can find in there.

What that means is: Your IntelliJ IDE *is* using your TomEE installation. It is starting up the server, then deploys your app in it.